# Cannot save git-bash window options

Tags: git-bash, mintty

I'm not able to save the mintty windows options due to a not properly set home folder in company's computer.

I've edited `etc/profile`, adding:

```
# Added by myself
# set-up home properly
HOME=/c/Users/myuser
HOMESHARE=/c/Users/myuser
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=/Users/myuser/
```

and indeed all the variables are set properly in the bash environment:

```
$ echo $HOME $HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH $HOMESHARE
/c/Users/myuser C:/Users/myuser/ /c/Users/myuser
```

However, when right click the git-bash window to change options line color, fonts, etc and try to save, it says:

> Could not save options to 'X:.minttyrc'. Permission denied.

We do have a company drive called X: and some windows variables are pointing to it. However no variable in the bash environment is point to X: as checked calling `printenv` in git-bash.

How to I tell mintty which folder to use as home?

I'm using [git-bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win) 2.19.2 for windows. The git-bash is running mintty 2.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like, some environmental variables in `git-bash` in windows are defined by the variables available in the windows environment, prior to git reading `profile`.

To solve that, instead of calling `git-bash` directly, I've made a batch file setting these variable properly:

```
set HOMEDRIVE=C:
set HOMEPATH=\Users\username\
\path\to\git-bash.exe %1
```

That worked fine.

---

Note 1:
To fix the `Git Bash Here` menu item, edit registry. Search for all entries calling `git-bash.exe` and replace by the bat file.

---

None 2: 
I don't have admin rights to the workstation I use so I can't edit `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` in the system.

Comment: what do you mean by "edit HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH in the system? Is it in registry or elsewhere?